# How to create SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to create sql query. So, I create sql fiddle for you with data [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82e09).

```
CREATE TABLE `passages_table` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`INSIDE` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`TAG` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
```

)

I need to group records by TAG where every tag should have sum of difference between dates that have INSIDE == 1 and date that have INSIDE == 0

result should be like (example)
TAG   |INTERVAL (minutes)
"---" | 40
"---" | 1450

[image]

Comment: and what have you tried

Comment: I don't understand how to get sum of difference

Comment: mysql has a function to calculate differences in dates http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus, I know about this function, I don't understand how to write sql that gets sum of difference of dates where every date belongs to INSIDE

Comment: You have tagged both mysql and slq-server which are you using because the answer even though I would still like more details will likely depend on your platform

Comment: shouldn't your result be 120 minutes and 90 minutes?

Comment: @TinTran oh no, it just example of result

Comment: are your pairs to calculate difference always going to be a row that has 0 inside with a minimal id that is greater than a row that has 1 inside? Because you'll need to be able to pair them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my try not exactly sure how you would pair them so i add a relationship here to look for the smallest id that is greater with same tag and inside = 0

To get pairs it joins T1 with T2 where the conditions can be seen in query below.

```
SELECT TAG,SUM(secs_diff)/60 as `INTERVAL`
FROM
  (SELECT T1.INSIDE,T1.TAG,T1.DATE,
         T2.INSIDE INSIDE2,T2.TAG TAG2,T2.DATE DATE2,
         TIME_TO_SEC(T2.DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(T1.DATE) as secs_diff          
  FROM passages_table T1
  INNER JOIN passages_table T2 ON
  T1.TAG = T2.TAG AND T1.INSIDE = 1 AND T2.INSIDE = 0
  AND T2.ID > T1.ID
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM passages_table T3
                    WHERE T3.ID > T1.ID AND T3.ID < T2.ID AND T3.TAG = T1.TAG)
  )T
GROUP BY TAG
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b82e09/10